# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString changes the actual string for hebrew letters

Tags: c#, encoding, query-string

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("tap=%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a4%d7%94", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8"))
```

returns this result:

```
tap=%uf7b5%u00a6%uf7b5%u0095%uf7b5%u00a4%uf7b5%u0094
```

Tried several encodings, but all returns a different string that was sent.

how can I keep the original formatting of the string ?

The original string decodes (by Url Decode tool set on utf8) to this hebrew string:
צופה

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `query` string is already encoded, so specifying an `Encoding` will try to re-encode it again.

If you use the other overload which does not anticipate an `Encoding` then it will work fine:

```
var col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("tap=%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a4%d7%94"); 
foreach (string key in col) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {col[key]}");
```

The output will be

```
tap: צופה
```

Comment: I've started without encoding - this is the result: 
tap=%u05e6%u05d5%u05e4%u05d4

Comment: @Dani [Here is code on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/di5qHQ). Do you set the culture in your application? (In case of the dotnet fiddle it is `en-US`)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgzIyB - I need this to return "true" but it's false. b/c it changes the string.

Comment: @Dani Since ParseQueryString decodes the query string, you need to encode it: HttpUtility.UrlEncode(col[key])

Comment: @Dani in your example code the expected value starts with the equals sign, I think it is just a copy paste mistake.

Comment: @Dani [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e18a77feff92fe6cdf8b891aa3b44fb1acb972d1/src/libraries/System.Web.HttpUtility/src/System/Web/HttpUtility.cs#L83) is the source code of the ParseQueryString where you can see that UrlDecode is called on the Substring.